# New construction roof sheet broken from inside at corner edging

Tags: roof

in a new construction with framing I see roof sheet broken/missing at one corner. This was brought up in the framing inspection. What is the ideal way of fixing this? Builder was telling that they can punch in wood blocks from inside. Any recommendation is helpful

[image]

Update:
It’s fixed like below with wood blocks punched from underneath. Looks like not a reliable option. Any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: The blocks are just cosmetic, so they only need to reliably remain up in place. Do you anticipate them falling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roof sheathing does two things:

- It supports loads like roofing material and people, and
- it provides a "diaphragm" to prevent the walls from racking. Imagine a rectangular shaped floor layout deforming into a parallelogram, where the sheathing restrains things into a rigid rectangular shape.

The roof surface in this area has another roof above it, so the sheathing isn't necessary for supporting loads.

The hole in the diaphragm is similar in size to roof penetrations that ordinarily don't catch your eye (or your inspector's eye). A single roof vent probably has a very similar total area as this jagged hole in your sheathing. There's therefore no reason to worry about the roof diaphragm either.

That makes this hole a craftsmanship issue, not a structural issue. Slapping a square piece of OSB up there to hide the defect from below would be plenty sufficient. I suppose during demolition somebody might trust his weight to that patch, so maybe it should be fastened to support the "punching shear" demands of the roof. That seems silly, though.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like poor craftsmanship. Instead of cutting it, someone just smashed the corner with a hammer and *made it fit*.

You could put some blocking underneath to better support the area which should be sufficient. I would use a 2x6 or 2x8, laying flat and nailed/screwed between the trusses.

The other option is to remove the roofing in the area and replace the sheet, this seems unnecessary though.

Comment: Thanks. Is that black sheet visible from outside is a concern that can lead to any water leak in future?

Comment: The black is likely the roofing felt or an ice/water shield.. The sheathing damage is unlikely to cause water leaks.